# How to Read XML In in C# 

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

It may sounds a very basic question, but here it is. I have this sample XML loaded in DOM

```
<message from="fromvalue" to="tovalue" xml:lang="en" type="chat">
   <thread>{fe422b47-9856-4404-8c35-5ff45e43ee01}</thread> 
   <body>Test buddy</body> 
   <active xmlns="http://XXXX.org/protocol/chatstates" /> 
 </message>
```

This i am receiving from request body using the following piece of code

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader ( HttpContext.Request.InputStream,        System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 );
string sXMLRequest = reader.ReadToEnd ( );
XmlDocument xmlRequest = new XmlDocument ( );
xmlRequest.LoadXml ( sXMLRequest );
```

Now all i need to have is value of three things in three different variable

```
string bodytext = {body element inner text}
string msgfrom = {from attribute value of message element}
string msgto =   {to attribute value of message element}
```

I am using C#, can anyone put some minutes from their precious time and guide me, will appreciate that highly

Comment: Tried different things, but always disappointed at the end that include xmlreader and few other things, :(

Comment: Please add what you've tried and the results to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use LINQ to XML here - it's *much* simpler:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Request.InputStream);
string bodyText = (string) doc.Root.Element("body");
string fromAddress = (string) doc.Root.Attribute("from");
string toAddress = (string) doc.Root.Attribute("to");
```

That will give you a value of `null` for any element/attribute which isn't present. If you're happy with a NullReferenceException instead:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Request.InputStream);
string bodyText = doc.Root.Element("body").Value;
string fromAddress = doc.Root.Attribute("from").Value;
string toAddress = doc.Root.Attribute("to").Value;
```

Comment: Thanks you too, although i have adopted first answer as my solution, still thank you for your time and effort and correct solution

Comment: @VikasChawla: Note that using `XDocument.Load` means you don't need to *assume* the request stream will be UTF-8. So long as the document declares the appropriate encoding, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) which is the new XML parser that was introduced in .NET 3.5:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(sXMLRequest);
string bodytext = doc.Element("message").Element("body").Value;
string msgfrom = doc.Element("message").Attribute("from").Value;
string msgto = doc.Element("message").Attribute("to").Value;
```

Comment: What's the difference between Parse and Load?

Comment: `Load` expects stream, reader or filename. `Parse` expects a string which already represents XML which is what the OP already has.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: The OP already has it through doing unnecessary work *and* assuming UTF-8. Using `Load` means less code in total, and more reliability in the face of non-UTF-8 documents, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I much prefer XLINQ, however in your examples case:

```
XmlNode thread_node = xmlRequest.SelectSingleNode("/message/thread");
Guid thread = thread_node.InnerText;

XmlNode body_node = xmlRequest.SelectSingleNode("/message/body");
string body= body_node.InnerText;
```

Etc...

Comment: Thanks you too, although i have adopted first answer as my solution, still thank you for your time and effort and correct solution

Answer (score -1):

It's quite easy to serialize / deserialize between Xml and a C# class:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization

You basically create a class that holds the elements and attributes of the Xml, stick [XmlElement] and [XmlAttribute] attributes on them, and use the `XmlSerializer`.

There are other options; the `XmlReader` you already mentioned requires alot of work / maintenance, and is generally only used for large documents. The other answers I've seen sofar use readers of a higher abstraction level that are easy to use and do not use such a proxy class. I guess it's a matter of preference.

Comment: Care to share why this is downvoted? I don't learn anything from just a downvote.

Comment: Probably because serialization is massive overkill here, IMO.